# Install headers in corresponding directories

Tags: header-files, qmake, build-system

I am trying to install headers of my library using QMake. These headers gave a hierarchical order that must be applied on installation target as well. My current solution for this is to add many targets (each for one subdirectory):

```
...
headers.path = /usr/include/foo/widgets
headers_base.path = /usr/include/foo/widgets
headers_data.path = /usr/include/foo/widgets/data
headers_editors.path = /usr/include/foo/widgets/editors
...
HEADERS_BASE += \
    foo.hpp \
    bar.hpp
HEADERS_DATA += \
    data/foo.hpp \
    data/bar.hpp
HEADERS_EDITORS += \
    editors/foo.hpp \
    editors/bar.hpp
...
HEADERS += $$HEADERS_BASE \
    $$HEADERS_DATA \
    $$HEADERS_EDITORS
```

This is tedius and error-prune. I would like to use something simple and straightforward like `nobase` in autotools. Something like this:

```
magic_HEADERS += \
    foo.hpp \
    bar.hpp
    data/foo.hpp \
    data/bar.hpp
    editors/foo.hpp \
    editors/bar.hpp
```

**Note**

Having

```
HEADERS += \
    foo.hpp \
    bar.hpp
    data/foo.hpp \
    data/bar.hpp
    editors/foo.hpp \
    editors/bar.hpp
```

Installs all headers in a single directory.

Answer (score 0):

Headers will be installed if you change .pro file with example:

```
HEADERS += \
    include/widgets/foo.hpp \
    include/widgets/bar.hpp \
    include/widgets/data/foo.hpp \
    include/widgets/data/bar.hpp \
    include/widgets/editors/foo.hpp \
    include/widgets/editors/bar.hpp

unix {
    headers.path = /usr/local/include
    headers.files = $$PWD/include/*

    target.path = /usr/local/lib
    INSTALLS += target headers
}
```